# Curly braces with f-strings - ValueError: Sign not allowed in string format specifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

The following code:

```
a = 0
b = f'{"c": {a}}'
```

throws the error: `ValueError: Sign not allowed in string format specifier`
How to fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Escape the braces like this.

```
>>> f'{{"c": {a}}}'
'{"c": 0}'
```